# Disable rotation of a UINavigationController in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I have a `UINavigationController` which creates an instance of `UIViewController` and sets another `UIViewController` as it's root. I then present the navigation controller and everything works.

The problem comes when the user rotates the device. All my controllers (including root and excluding `UINavigationController`) implement the `shouldAutorotate` and return `FALSE`.

Somehow, my views still rotate. We come to the centre of my problem. I create and present the navigation controller like so:

```
AwesomeViewController *controller = [[AwesomeViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self presentViewController:navController 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:NULL];
```

It is pretty straight forward as you can see.

1. The `navController` is missing its `shouldAutorotate` set to `FALSE` and that's why it's rotating, am I correct?
2. How to lock it in portrait orientation?
3. Can it be done without making a ridiculous subclass like this:

   ```
   @interface LockedRotationNavigationController : UINavigationController
   @end

   @implementation LockedRotationNavigationController
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate { return NO; }
   @end
   ```

What I'm actually looking for is how to **disable rotation of the `UINavigationController`** without subclassing it?

The property is `readonly` so I'm out of ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to disable rotations globally in the app or just for this particular navigation controller?

Comment: Globally would be good as well. Do I still get the notifications about the rotation if I register for them via the `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];`? Then it would be fine.

Comment: Oh and please post it as answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Feel free to also upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable rotations globally in your app in `Info.plist` expand **`Supported interface orientations`** and remove **Landscape** items to make your application only run in portrait mode.

[image]

Or you can just select supported orientations in **Xcode** like this:

[image]

You can also lock the rotation programmatically by implementing **`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`** method in your view controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```